# Umount -f pc can not recognize grub2

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I executed umount -a -f /  to unmount all devices.after restarting
system i can not see ubuntu choice of grub2,i mean grub2
Does not come.i am alone with the bios of dell  inspiron 15r .
How can i  make pc recognize grub2 menu.

Comment: Yes i did what you say and it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grub configuration and the bootfiles are located in /boot directory. Please state clearly what you want to accomplish. If you have accidently unmounted the root partition then try running your system with a usb bootable linux. and try to repiar it then using a distro cd...